# Prevent html5 Canvas from clearing when window is blurred. (requestAnimationFrame)

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, requestanimationframe

I made a simple canvas animation using a function which clears and redraws the canvas, and the calling requestAnimationFrame, It works awesome but when the window is blurred for long, say 10 secs, then the canvas clears itself and nothing's drawn. May anybody give an Idea why it's happening and how to solve it?

The structure of function is like :-

```
function drawFrame(time){
    //clear and redraw to be understood as working functions in prototype    ...
    canvas.clear();
    canvas.redraw();
    requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
    }
requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
```

Comment: What do you mean by blurred?

Comment: We would like to examinate your 'clear()' & 'redraw()' methods. Animating is complex, and even a bad statement can ruin or crash your program.

Comment: Blurred means while I switch to another tab. and when I switch to the animation tab again, it clears itself :p